# NSString stringWithUTF8String in swift for char[]

Tags: swift

In my .h file typedef looks like -> [I am using bridging header to import the .h file in Swift]

```
typedef struct {
  char xyzID[16];
} XYZ;
```

Now in ObjectiveC to convert `xyzID[]` into `NSString` it looks like ->

```
NSString *xid=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:XYZ.xyzID];
```

I have tried but somtimes the error is like "Cannot invoke initializer for type with an argument list of type '(Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8)'"

So how can I can do the same thing in Swift (to convert `xyzID[]` into `NSString`)?

Comment: Please share the link for previous question!

Comment: You should find it in your question, right after "This question already has an answer here:".

Comment: It Worked Dude. Thanks a Lot.!